# Why is the JavaScript file parsed as PHP in my Cake plugin?

Tags: php, javascript, parsing, cakephp, plugins

I've got a problem with one of my JavaScripts included in a Cake plugin I'm developing. For some reason a JavaScript file is parsed as a PHP file, so loading the file throws this error, which is a PHP parsing error:

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

The script is called using the HtmlHelper:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script(array(
  '/myplugin/scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce',
)); ?>
```

The error is triggered by a compressed `tiny_mce.js` file which resides in a subdirectory in a scripts dir, the uncompressed version displays the same behaviour. The thing is that I haven't got the problem on my local setup.

The remote server is running PHP 5.2.17 with `mod_rewrite` enabled, my Cake version is 1.3.10 - my test setup runs PHP 5.3.4 and the same version of Cake.
It could be a rewrite or permissions error, but my application functions fine otherwise and other scripts (including those in subdirectories and remote ones) load without problem.

**EDIT:**
After moving the tiny_mce directory out of the Cake installation and linking to it the JavaScript is parsed correctly. My guess it's a bug relating to mod_rewrite and the handling of plugins, but I haven't found other cases related to this behaviour.

Comment: Could your production server have `.js` files setup to be compiled by the PHP interpreter?  This is the only thing I could think of as causing this.

Comment: I would try to write `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/tiny_mce.js">` into the view directly to test if server handles it. If yes, then the problem should be in cakephp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also come across this issue, with exactly the same file: Tiny MCE JavaScript.

This is due to the way that the CakePHP dispatcher handles files in a plugin's webroot. It chooses to do a PHP include on files with CSS or JS extensions, and it just so happens that the tiny_mce.js file contains the characters `<?`, meaning that instead of just outputting JavaScript text it tries to parse the subsequent lines as PHP code. Unsurprisingly it fails!

This has been [raised as a bug](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1853) on Lighthouse (CakePHP's bug tracking system). The suggested fixes are:

1. Create a symbolic link from the plugin webroot to the app webroot (e.g. `app/webroot/tinymce => app/Plugin/TinyMCE/webroot`)
2. Turn off PHP short tags in your PHP INI - a good principle anyway

In short, CakePHP may not fix this, as they want to maintain support for being able to include PHP code in JS/CSS files.

Comment: Thanks for all the research! Short tags are disabled on my local server, but a lot of hosters unfortunately choose to enable the feature. I've reverted to the practice of storing the `tiny_mce.js` in the `app` webroot, as suggested in the bug report.

Comment: No problem. I think that's the problem with the "solutions" - you can't always control the PHP config on servers that you're deploying to. CakePHP said that they may change this in the future, so fingers crossed!

Comment: [PHP interpretation of plugin/theme assets has been removed](https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/changesets/f25ee98144548f62af8914094608301f73d7c282). However, it's not in the current version of CakePHP (2.3) and I'm not sure why (the commit was 6 months ago, but 2.3 was released about 1 month ago).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the js file into APP/plugins/your_plugin/webroot/js/ and access them like /your_plugin/js/file.js. If you dont do that the dispatcher wont be able to pass you the right file and try to load a controller instead.

Comment: Having the script inside another directory instead of the default js is not a problem for Cake. Also it isn't strictly necessary to append a .js extension, the HtmlHelper does this for you. Cake's dispatcher might indeed by trying to load the JavaScript as a controller, but unfortunately it doesn't make a difference when I reference it as `/myplugin/js/` or `myplugin/scripts/`.