# TinyMCE error with .htaccess and CakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, tinymce

I'm experiencing some trouble when including TinyMCE js files in my production environment.

**The problem:**

- Evertything works great but tinymce.min.js fails to load. When I try to see the file in the browser it appears to be blank. I found a 500 server error for that request so I think .htacess rewrites can be the reason.
- Any other js file made by me works correctly and can be read in a browser through it's url.
- If I change the contents of tinymce.min.js the file is read and works fine.

**CakePHP Installation:**

It's in a shared host and I've done the following to get it to work:

- app, plugin, vendor and lib directories are one level up the public_html directory. (in my case /home2/username/)
- the contents from webroot  were copied into /home2/username/public_html
- Finally I modified Cake's constant ROOT to match /home2/username/ in the copied index.php file from webroot.

As I said before the only thing I can think about is htaccess doing something when tinymce.min.js starts including other js files but I'm no expert in apache or rewrite rules. Everything else works perfectly.

**Views:**

The javascript files are included in admin_add and admin_edit views for articles using the html helper, they're not between head html tags.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('tinymce/tinymce.min'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('tinymce/init'); ?>
```

as an example my admin_add.ctp looks like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('tinymce/tinymce.min'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('tinymce/init'); ?>
<div class="articulo prev">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Articulo'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Crear Articulo'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('titulo');
        echo $this->Form->input('contenido');
        echo $this->Form->input('categoria_id', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $categorias, 'label' => 'Categoria', 'empty' => 'Seleccionar'));
        echo $this->Form->input('fecha');
        echo $this->Form->input('usuario_id');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="links_interes">
    <title><?php echo __('Acciones'); ?></title>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Listar Articulos'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Listar Usuarios'), array('controller' => 'usuarios', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Crear Usuario'), array('controller' => 'usuarios', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your layout? I am interested in seeing how you call the JS files

Comment: Post edited to add the actual code for one of the views, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days researching I found this: [Why is the JavaScript file parsed as PHP in my Cake plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518126/why-is-the-javascript-file-parsed-as-php-in-my-cake-plugin)

I couldn't try any of the mentioned solutions in that post because of hosting restrictions, can't edit php.ini and php function symlink(); doesn't work so...

- Created a _noUrlReWrite directory at website's root.
- Copied the tinymce directory there.
- Added a rule to .htaccess so the directory remains unaffected by cake's rewrite rules:

  `RewriteRule ^_noUrlReWrite/(.*) _noUrlReWrite/$1 [L]`
- Finally chaged the script call to load with the full url

  echo $this->Html->script('http://www.sitesdomain.com/_noUrlReWrite/js/tinymce/init.js');

And there was working, then came up another problem, tinymce's toolbar characters looked weird, like wrong encoding.

The problem was with firefox and is because: `Firefox (which supports @font-face from v3.5) does not allow cross-domain fonts by default. This means the font must be served up from the same domain (and sub-domain) unless you can add an “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” header to the font.`

Then I created another .htaccess in tinymce folder with:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|tiff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

**And problem solved!**